# Google analytics is tracking my admin panel usage. I removed the code, can I delete the data?

Tags: google-analytics, seo

I accidentally put Google Analytics code in such a way that it included it throughout the entire website, including the admin panel.
As a result, when I go to the site content page to view all the pages seen by Google Analytics, it now shows all the pages in my website, including all kinds of admin panel pages.

1. After having removed the Google Analytics code from the admin panel now, will it eventually
   remove all the admin pages where it's no longer there, and if so,
   how long might it take?
2. Is there a way to remove these pages from the site content page manually, other than using advanced filtering them?
3. If I create an advanced filter, filtering all of these pages, will this filter somehow be available to other users with access to this account, or is the filter local and/or temporary?

Answer (score 2):

1. Google will stop recording visits to those pages after you remove the tracking code from them. Any previously collected data will still be available in Google Analytics. If you want to stop seeing that data in your analytics, then you create a seperate profile and label it as "After admin tracking got removed". Or, you will need to add an annotation to your analytics and start looking at the data from the date that you removed the tracking code.
2. Can't remove them manually. You can create a segment that excludes those pages, but once that segment is disabled, they will show up again :-)
3. Filters can be seen/available to all users, but can only be edited by managers. If you add a filter, it will only apply to data collected after it has been applied. Any previously collected data will still show up in Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

If Google Analytics has the data about the admin pages in the data range that you are looking at, then the admin pages will show up in the reports.

The default date range in Google Analytics is 30 days.   After 30 days, you will no longer see the admin pages by default when log into Google Analytics.   In the meantime, you could restrict your date range to only show data since your tracking code was removed from the admin pages.   There is a date widget in the upper right of the Google Analytics pages that can do that.

I don't know of any way that you can remove some data from Google Analytics once it has collected it.